# Grabbing Kubernetes Secrets With .yml for Kubeless Bots

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, kubeless

I have worked on grabbing Kubernetes secrets with a `.yml` file for weeks, but to no avail. My script is currently triggered by a `KafkaTrigger`, which cannot pull in secrets from Kubernetes. Grabbing the secrets, we are left with two possibilities: 1) pull in secrets from python or 2) create a second `.yml` file. Option 1) is not possible, since I would still need an `.ssh` key in my `requirements.txt` file, exposing an internal code base. Ideally, the .yml could pull in the `.ssh` key. My question is: how could you create a `.yml` file with two scripts running, a) the `KafkaTrigger`, and b) the code which pulls in secrets? The `KafkaTrigger` should not change, so what changes can I make to get the `.yml` logic to work? In particular, are the apiVersions and kind correct? Do I need an image for this code to work?

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-bot-grab-secrets
  namespace: name
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-bot-grab-secrets
        image: img
        env:
          - name: SQL_URI
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: SECRET_NAME
                key: SQLALCHEMY_URI
```

Please tell me if these questions are not clear! Thanks!

Comment: What is a `KafkaTrigger`?  Where does this credential need to wind up in the end?  Can you inject a Secret value into it as an environment variable like you've done in the example?  (A separate Deployment almost certainly cannot do this.)

Comment: A KafkaTrigger is the namespace for a Kafka event listener. I.E., it will wait for a process to happen and then trigger a script when a condition is met. I would like to pull in the environmental variable into the pod so it can be used by my python script. In sum, here is the logic: process happens, .yml file triggers script and pulls secrets, script runs (using the secrets) within Kubernetes pod/

Comment: The problem is that you cannot pull a secret using ```apiVersion: kubeless.io/v1beta1```.  Using a dev.env file would be too static and it would not change as the secrets change within the key vault. How could you get around these problems?